# Laravel: A non well formed numeric value encountered (calculating)

Tags: php, laravel, math

currently I'm following the tut https://github.com/drehimself/laravel-ecommerce-example and I've been bumping on  some errors as the following one:

A non well formed numeric value encountered

this time is about my Coupon model line 18:

> 

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coupon extends Model { 
    public static function findByCode($code)
    {
        return self::where('code', $code)->first();
    }
    public function discount($total)
    {
        if ($this->type == 'fixed') {
            return $this->value;
        } elseif ($this->type == 'percent') {
            return round(($this->percent_off / 100) * $total);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 
}
```

due this I can't show the result nor load the page.. can someone help me please? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You have to give us a little more here... what is getting passed in the $total value? Is it numeric?

Comment: The only way I could replicate this was by setting your $this->percent_off value to a non-numeric string. You probably have $this->percent_off equal to '10%' or something similar. Make sure you remove the % sign from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to an int, but I would personally find out what the value `$this->percent_off` is equal to... But the following should work...

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coupon extends Model { 
    public static function findByCode($code)
    {
        return self::where('code', $code)->first();
    }
    public function discount($total)
    {
        if ($this->type == 'fixed') {
            return $this->value;
        } elseif ($this->type == 'percent') {
            return round(((int)$this->percent_off / 100) * $total);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 
}
```